debian command line keeps adding newline
Sorry if this is an easy one, I've tried searching and it's started to annoy me now.
On one of my (Debian) servers the command prompt insists on adding a new line every time. So it looks like this:
name@servername ~/directory
 %

how can I get rid if the newline after the directory name, so that I am typing on the same line as name@servername ~/directory and not underneath it.
There is no .bashrc file that I can find, and this is the only server that does it. Where else could this be controlled from?

echo $SHELL:
/bin/zsh

echo $PS1:
%K{blue}%n@%m%k %B%F{cyan}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white} %# %b%f%k

(probably explains why .bashrc doesn't exist)

The prompt variable (PS1) that you show does not cause a newline to be inserted.  Does this only occur in a particular directory (with a newline in its name), or does the newline always appear?

it seems to be to do with the directory name length. 4 characters and it behaves how I expect (no new line). 5 characters or more, and it inserts a newline. Also the short directory names show in cyan, the longer ones in green

check for setopt PROMPT_SP or PROMPT_SUBST https://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows

New line after going into folder terminal https://superuser.com/questions/1681201/new-line-after-going-into-folder-terminal

That certainly fixes the problem. It is strange though that this server is set to prompt adam1 the same as the others, but it behaves differently.

Best to avoid echo to check things as it mangles backslashes. What's the output of typeset -p {,R}P{S1,ROMPT}

Did you manage to solve the problem with the links and the answers? If not, I will delete my response.

As you mention in comment that you use the adam1 prompt theme¹, see: New line after going into folder terminal on the superuser.com sister site:

The definition of the adam1 is in the /usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/prompt_adam1_setup. A look at this file confirms it is rather complex : it measures the prompt length and compare to 40. If the prompt is too large, a newline is inserted before the %.

Here your prompt is likely more than 40 characters wide.
See also: Add newline to prompt if it's too long
The adam1 prompt theme does something similar as the bash answer does there:
$ autoload -Uz promptinit
$ promptinit
$ prompt adam1
user@host ~ % typeset -p precmd_functions
typeset -a precmd_functions=( prompt_adam1_precmd )
user@host ~ % typeset -f prompt_adam1_precmd
prompt_adam1_precmd () {
        setopt localoptions noxtrace nowarncreateglobal
        local base_prompt_expanded_no_color base_prompt_etc
        local prompt_length space_left
        base_prompt_expanded_no_color=$(print -P "$base_prompt_no_color")
        base_prompt_etc=$(print -P "$base_prompt%(4~|...|)%3~")
        prompt_length=${#base_prompt_etc}
        if [[ $prompt_length -lt 40 ]]
        then
                path_prompt="%B%F{$prompt_adam1_color2}%(4~|...|)%3~%F{white}"
        else
                space_left=$(( $COLUMNS - $#base_prompt_expanded_no_color - 2 ))
                path_prompt="%B%F{$prompt_adam1_color3}%${space_left}<...<%~$prompt_newline%F{white}"
        fi
        PS1="$base_prompt$path_prompt %# $post_prompt"
        PS2="$base_prompt$path_prompt %_> $post_prompt"
        PS3="$base_prompt$path_prompt ?# $post_prompt"
}
user@host ~ % typeset -p base_prompt
typeset base_prompt='%K{blue}%n@%m%k '

The 40 is hardcoded there.
If you don't like that behaviour, you can use a different prompt theme.
Changing that hardcoded value could be done with:
functions[prompt_adam1_precmd]=$functions[prompt_adam1_precmd]:s/40/60

(to be put after prompt adam1 if in ~/.zshrc).

¹ That's the prompt theme that is enabled by default on Debian if upon first invocation, you select this answer in the zsh-newuser-install framework:

(2)  Populate your ~/.zshrc with the configuration recommended
     by the system administrator and exit (you will need to edit
     the file by hand, if so desired).


Prompt themes were introduced in 1999 by Adam Spiers, hence the adam1 which was the first prompt theme he suggested.

This one server does have a particularly long name. A quick count of the characters shows that changing to a 5 character directory name, does indeed hit the 40 character limit.

I changed the function to 60 characters and it now looks much better, I'll also know what's happening when it inevitably happens again. cheers,
